# Byte array to int16 conversion

Tags: f#, arrays, seq

How would one take a byte array and convert it into a multidimensional integer array.  The real data would actually be the results of a System.IO.BinaryReader using ReadBytes.  The function would take the byte array and output the new array.

For instance, the given data would have the first 4 elements in a 4xN array of 
256, 328, 344, 546

The following conversion works for a single pair of bytes

```
let value = int bytedata.[1] ||| (int bytedata.[0] <<< 8)
```

I can do it with looping, however it seems that F# should make this easier.

```
let realdata =  [|1uy; 0uy; 1uy; 48uy; 0uy; 158uy; 0uy; 222uy; 0uy; 250uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy;
151uy; 2uy; 238uy; 3uy; 31uy; 1uy; 191uy; 1uy; 228uy; 1uy; 62uy; 1uy;
111uy; 0uy; 247uy; 1uy; 183uy; 0uy; 83uy; 0uy; 213uy; 2uy; 197uy; 2uy;
161uy; 1uy; 7uy; 0uy; 201uy; 1uy; 48uy; 0uy; 166uy; 0uy; 133uy; 1uy; 40uy;
0uy; 150uy; 0uy; 193uy; 2uy; 207uy; 2uy; 217uy; 1uy; 158uy; 1uy; 53uy; 1uy;
38uy; 0uy; 141uy; 0uy; 162uy; 1uy; 23uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy; 128uy; 2uy; 223uy;
2uy; 204uy; 1uy; 236uy; 2uy; 20uy; 1uy; 56uy; 0uy; 221uy; 0uy; 235uy; 1uy;
118uy; 0uy; 29uy; 0uy; 173uy; 2uy; 58uy; 2uy; 27uy; 1uy; 56uy;|]

let convertBytes (data : byte[]) =
seq { 
    let i = ref 0
    while !i < 10 do
        if !i%2 = 0 then 
            yield int(data.[!i] ||| (data.[!i+1] <<< 8))
        i := !i + 2
}
```

However, I'm yielding a byte array rather than a int16 array.

Don

Comment: You probably want to cast `data.[!i]` etc to `int16` berfore you do the bitshifting / oring

Answer (score 2):

First of all I will assume you want a single-dimension array, at least in your sample code that's what you are getting.

Second, your conversion math seems wrong to me, if you take `[1uy; 48uy]` and your result is 49, what is the result of `[0uy; 49uy]`? It looks like you're adding rather than converting.

So correct me if I'm wrong but I think this is what you need:

```
open System
let result = 
    [|0..2..Array.length realdata-1|] 
    |> Array.map (fun i -> BitConverter.ToInt16(realdata, i))

// val r : int16 [] = [|1s; 12289s; -25088s; -8704s; -1536s; 0s; ...
```

Alternatively if the data is Big Endian:

```
let result = 
    [|0..2..Array.length realdata-1|] 
    |> Array.map (fun i -> (int16 (realdata.[i]) <<< 8) ||| int16 (realdata.[i+1]))
```

Or you can replace the expression in the lambda with your conversion if it makes sense for you.

**UPDATE**

From your comments, you may want to do something like this:

```
let result = 
    Array2D.init 8 (realdata.Length/16) (fun i j -> (int16 (realdata.[j * 16 + i*2]) <<< 8) ||| int16 (realdata.[j * 16 + i*2 + 1]))
```

Comment: Gustavo, my math was wrong, but not by adding.  The [1uy; 48uy] I mistakenly converted to hex 0148 giving decimal 328.  I actually needed to convert to hex 0130 giving decimal 304.  Your second code snippet did the trick for Big Endian.

Comment: Additionally, I do want to map the array into a multidimensional array, rather than a single dimensional array, but I am going one step at a time.

Comment: @dgp How many dimensions? Be aware that you can manipulate a maximum of 4 dimensions. With F# 4.0 you will be able to manipulate up to 32 dimensions which is the .NET limit.

Comment: Just 2 dimensions.  The actual data is row / col ordered with 8 parameters in a row.  I want to map it into a (8 x N) array.  What is the F# convenience for doing that type of reshaping?

Comment: @dgp You can use `array2D` which takes a jagged array or you can directly create and initialise the array with `Array2D.init`

Comment: The update was perfect code for conversion from byte[] to int16 multidimensional array.